# "Use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_key'"

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, sqlcipher, podspec

I've been working in a module that i want to distribute as a Pod, this module depends on an external library 'SQLCipher'. In the module i have defined the podspec with the corresponding dependency, of SQLCipher like this:

```
s.dependency 'SQLCipher'
```

and when i compile it as a framework it gives me no errors, but when i add my module to another project as a pod, some of the methods are not found or recognized, even though they are inside the same classes as methods that work.

To be more specific the method that is not working from SQLCipher is

```
sqlite3_key
```

this is an example of the code that is not working

```
rc = sqlite3_key(db, password, Int32(password.utf8CString.count))
```

and I get the following error:

```
"Use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_key'"
```

Just to be clear, SQLCipher is imported into the class all of the other methods from SQLCipher work fine in the same context like for example:

```
rc = sqlite3_open(documentsURL?.path, &db)
```

This method is in the same class as sqlite3_key.

Comment: Have you imported the module?

Comment: You might need to do `import SQLCipher` when needed.

Comment: Yes, the module SQLCipher is imported, all other methods of SQLCipher, like the one mentioned above 'sqlite3_open' work fine in the same context, is just 'sqlite3_key' that does not seem to find the reference to the method even though it shares the same class as 'sqlite3_open'